# Saving data using XML in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I use the following code for saving.Updating records to Oracle,

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();

// Create the command.
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", con);
cmd.CommandText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
    "<ROWSET>\n" +
    " <MYROW>\n" +
    " <FIELD1>2</FIELD1>\n" +
    " <FIELD2>zafar</FIELD2>\n" +
    " </MYROW>\n" +
    "</ROWSET>\n";

// Set the XML save properties.
KeyColumnsList = new string[1];
KeyColumnsList[0] = "FIELD1";
UpdateColumnsList = new string[1];
UpdateColumnsList[0] = "FIELD2";

cmd.XmlSaveProperties.KeyColumnsList = KeyColumnsList;
cmd.XmlSaveProperties.UpdateColumnsList = UpdateColumnsList;
cmd.XmlSaveProperties.RowTag = "MYROW";
cmd.XmlSaveProperties.Table = "testconn";
cmd.XmlSaveProperties.Xslt = null;
cmd.XmlSaveProperties.XsltParams = null;
rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine("rows: " + rows);
```

In the `Field2` column I want to use `select user from dual`. I am not able to save current DB user.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use normal INSERT/UPDATE statements?

Comment: I want to save/Update multiple records at one go.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? Do you have some justifiable performance issues with doing standard update/inserts?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of data in the `CommandText` assumes that all values are literals. There is no way to have it recognize an inner query or expression. If you want to query the `user` you will have to do it separately and incorporate that into the data. This may be possible with the `Xslt` and `XsltParams` clauses.